# Are there any good WarpLDA python implementations?

Tags: r, python, scikit-learn, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm trying to implement LDA in either R or Python on a production system. I'd prefer Python because more of the team is comfortable with it, but either are an option.

In short, R's [text2vec](http://text2vec.org/topic_modeling.html#latent_dirichlet_allocation) package implements WarpLDA (from [this 2016 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.08628.pdf)) and performs more stable clustering and much faster than either popular Python option ([gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html#module-gensim.models.ldamulticore) and [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html)) which both implement Online Variational Bayers (from [this 2010 paper](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/mdhnips2010.pdf)).

Does anyone know of any stable, well-documented Python implementations of WarpLDA? I would love to be able to compare it to the R, so that I can get more of an apples-to-apples comparison.

Also, I'd be interested to know of any Python implementations of LightLDA or F+LDA, which are the two "state-of-the-art" algorithms that the aforementioned 2016 paper benchmarks itself against.

Thanks!
Seth